# Gitlab integrate with Active Directory

Tags: authentication, gitlab, active-directory, ldap

I run gitlab as docker container on ubuntu server and my Active Directory runs on Windows Server 2019, but after config `gitlab.rb` file for integration with Active Directory, I get this error:

> Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Connection timed out - user specified timeout"

My question: is that necessary join my Gitlab server host to Active Directory?

My gitlab.rb is :

```
gitlab_rails[‘ldap_enabled’] = true
###! remember to close this block with ‘EOS’ below
gitlab_rails[‘ldap_servers’] = YAML.load <<-‘EOS’
main: # ‘main’ is the GitLab ‘provider ID’ of this LDAP server
label: ‘Active Directory’
host:‘active directory ip’
port: 389
uid: ‘sAMAccountName’
method: ‘plain’ # “tls” or “ssl” or “plain”
bind_dn: ‘CN=Ldap Search,OU=All Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com’
password: ‘12345678’
active_directory: true
allow_username_or_email_login: false
block_auto_created_users: false
base: ‘OU=All Users,DC=domain,DC=com’
EOS
```

How do I solve my issue?

Gitlab users authenticate with Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue : write bind_dn: 'user@domain.com" instead of bind_dn: ‘CN=Ldap Search,OU=All Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com